# Drupal - Page not found for custom module

Tags: php, forms, drupal, drupal-7

I'm fairly new to Drupal and just made my first module wich shows a form. In the hook_menu(), I set $items['form'], as you can see below. While I navigate to mysite.com/form, it doesn't show me anything, except for the theme and: Page not found, The requested page "/form" could not be found.

I tried to clear my cache, to give my module a different name, made sure my module is enabled, nothing helps. Does anyone knows what the problem might be? The code from the .module file is right here:

```
<?php 

//implements hook_permission()
function form_example_permission() {
  return array(
    'Submit form_example' => array(
      'title' => t('Submit form_example'),
      'description' => t('Submit the form_example form'),
    ),
  );
}


//implements hook_menu()
function form_example_menu() {
  $items['form'] = array(
    'title' => 'My Example Form',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'acces' => TRUE,
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form()',
    'page arguments' => array('form_example_form'),
    'acces arguments' => array('acces content'),
  );

  return $items;
}

//implements hook_form()
function form_example_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['mynumber'] = array (
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('My Number'),
    '#size' => 10,
    '#maxlength' => 10,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#description' => t('Please enter a valid number'),
  );

  $form['mytextfield'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('My Textfield'),
    '#size' => 60,
    '#maxlength' => 128,
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );

  $form['mytext'] = array(
    '#title' => t('My Textarea'),
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#description' => t('Enter some text'),
    '#default value' => '',
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Add item'),
  );

  return $form;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but with drupal_get_form without brackets it still gives me a 404 error

Comment: comment would too long, that's why I removed it and put it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form()` is wrong, you need to remove brackets from function name. The right implementation will be `page callback' => 'drupal_get_form`. And also `acces => TRUE` is wrong, it must be 'access callback', and if you set fixed TRUE value then you don't need to specify `access arguments` key. Because `access callback` return TRUE anyway. For further [reading](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7)..

**UPDATE:**
Example:

```
function form_example_permission() {
  return array(
    'submit form_example' => array(
      'title' => t('Submit form_example'),
      'description' => t('Submit the form_example form'),
    ),
  );
}


//implements hook_menu()
function form_example_menu() {
  $items['form'] = array(
    'title' => 'My Example Form',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'access callback' => 'user_access',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('form_example_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('submit form_example'),
  );

  return $items;
}
```

(you had a typo in you code) Don't forget to flush the cache.

Comment: I followed your instructions and I'm now using: 

'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
'page arguments' => array('form_example_form'),
'acces callback' => array('acces content'),

wich still does not work. Are there any other possibilities outside the hook_menu?

Comment: @Elendas if you use `'acces arguments' => array('submit form_example')` then change `access callback => TRUE` to `access callback => user_access`

Comment: I'm now using: 

function form_example_menu() {
  $items['example/form'] = array(
    'title' => 'My Example Form',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('form_example_form'),
    'acces callback' => 'user_access',
    'acces arguments' => array('submit form_example'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
  
  return $items;
}

Wich still does not work, so I'm suspicious that it's somewhere outside the hook_menu. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Please change speling a `acces` to `access` and change the `drupal_get_form()` to `drupal_get_form` and after `clear a caches`

```
function form_example_menu() {
  $items['form'] = array(
    'title' => 'My Example Form',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'access' => TRUE,
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('form_example_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );

  return $items;
}
```